# Android: GPS altitude tracking for winter app

Tags: android, gps, altitude

I'm developing an application for Android that one of the purposes is to measure variation of elevation (altitudes). I am aware that today we are unable to get altitude data with high accuracy (even medium i guess). I stared to search alternatives, and I know that there are Global Elevation Data that I could probably use to my calculations (by the way - can you recommend some good data provider as I need this in offline mode on the device so it would be nice if I could download it in file and use inside app).

If GPS altitude doesn't work properly if you are trying to check it inside the building, I want to make sure that if you are on a **dry** ski slope - will it be incorrect too ?

Comment: check out the pressure sensor API for good quality altitude possibilities but not so good device availability but the S3 has one.

Comment: there are only plenty of smartphones containing pressure sensor so it's impossible to implement that solution to the problem.